# How to retrieve only unique rows based on multiple column check in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with these values present

```
Start  End  Status
A       B   12AXB
C       D   13AXB
B       A   12AXB
C       E   14AXB
U       X   12AXB
```

How can we retrieve only unique records like comparing `start` column and `end` column? As here start and end are the same for example for A & B and B & A so want to retrieve only one row out of this

Final output should be this

```
Start  End  Status
A       B   12AXB
C       D   13AXB
C       E   14AXB
U       X   12AXB
```

Comment: `GROUP BY GREATEST(start, end), LEAST(start, end)`

Comment: No this is not working ```could not prepare statement (1 no such function: GREATEST)```

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL?

Comment: Even i trying to run this query I am getting incorrect syntax ```SELECT
        *,
        Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION 
    BY
        start,
        end ) AS RN 
    FROM
        stat```

Comment: Yes i am sure i am using mysql

Comment: Works here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3QP2h8AYjHEHWZ2FyM9B8t/0

Comment: You need MySQL 8 to use window functions. What version do you have?